# The default XML namespace of the project must be the MSBuild XML namespace error after Installing .Net Core 3 in Visual Studio 2017.0

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2017

I had 3 projects in a C# solution in Visual Studio 2017,
All 3 projects were loaded correctly, but I was getting dependency errors on missing

```
.NETFramework 4.0
.NETFramework 4.6.1
.NETStandard 1.3
.NETStandard 2.0
```

Looking online, I saw that I needed .Net Core SDK
So I download the latest SDK for .NET Core 3

Now 2 of the 3 projects would not load with the error

`The default XML namespace of the project must be the MSBuild XML namespace`

Searches on this error all point to needing Visual Studio 2017 for new project file format

But I am already using Visual Studio 2017. 
So what is causing these projects to not open, did they change it again?
How do I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need Visual Studio 2019 if you want to use .NET Core 3.
2. If you want to stay with Visual Studio 2017 for some reasons - you can use .NET Core 2.1 which is supported in Visual Studio 2017.

   .NET Core 2.1. has LTS (Long Term Support) which ends in 2021.

Comment: I just want a consistent product that is backwards compatible like C++. This constant switching of frameworks and making products incompatible is highly bothersome.

Comment: Well, I agree, but this is pain of all big frameworks. C++ is just a language shipped with few tiny libraries. DotNet is a framework shipped with IDE and multiple language support (C#, VB, F#). You can use Java which is much better in compatibility between releases, but sucks in productivity, there is no WPF or any modern GUI engine (JavaFX is dead I suppose), no builtin MVC magic, RazorPages, and unsigned numbers.

Comment: C# 8.0 language itself is pretty compatibile with older releases.